# building dev container in VsCOde(Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to build a dev container in VsCode on Windows Os. The devcontainer seems to work (python  and its packages in requirements.txt are installed, uname returns linux, git is installed and all the files of my repo have been downloaded). The problem is that while the image is being built, the terminal shows me several errors:

```
[403 ms] Exit code 1
[404 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/root/.vscode-server/bin/abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d/node'
[405 ms] 
[406 ms] 
[406 ms] Exit code 1
[406 ms] Start: Run in host: uname -s
[411 ms] Linux
[1641 ms] Exit code 1
[1642 ms] Start: Run in host: mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist'

[1655 ms] Host server: /bin/sh: /root/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d/node: not found
[1656 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[1656 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[1659 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/ash
[1669 ms] Error: write EPIPE
        at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
        at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
        at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:930:11)
        at Socket._write (node:net:942:8)
        at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
        at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
        at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
        at my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:4981
        at d (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:100665)
        at t (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:100156)
        at my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:100184
        at my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:100829
        at my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:110031
        at Nk.e.read (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:109349)
        at Ro.request (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:106259)
        at o.remoteCall (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:1123)
        at my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:3852
        at i (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:1926)
        at e.<computed> [as exec] (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:1684)
        at p (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:122:2004)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:122:1982
        at hc (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:224:2041)
        at e6 (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:231:584)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at async Ry (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:227:498)
        at async dC (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:123:5133)
        at async nv (my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:289:35554)
        at async my_user_directory\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.309.0\dist\extension\extension.js:298:15341
[1670 ms] Could not connect to WSL.
[1670 ms] stream is closed
[1674 ms] Host server terminated (code: 127, signal: null).
```

In addition, if I click new terminal, this is what appears:

```
bash: my_docker_machine_directory/.bashrc: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'ash: my_docker_machine_directory/.bashrc: line 18: `for i in my_docker_machine_directory/*/lib; do
(venv39) bash-4.2$
```

there is a syntax error and in line 2 'ash instead of bash

can I ignore them or do I need to worry about ?

This is my devcontainer.json :

{
"name": "Existing Dockerfile",

```
"context": "..",
"dockerFile": "my_project_dockerfile_dir",
"build": {
    "target": "python-image-dev"
},

"settings": {},
"extensions": [
    "ms-python.python"
]
```

}